# Суммирование значений столбца в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Существует запрос который подсчитывает количество лекций, семинаров, лабораторных, студентов по каждой группе, и дисциплине:

```
SELECT `class`, `discipline`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_students`, 0)) AS `count_students`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лекция', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `lection`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Семинар', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `seminar`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `lab`,
    SUM(`type`='Лекция') AS `groups`,
    SUM(`type`='Лабораторная') AS `subgroups`,
    count('id') AS `numbe`,
    `course_semestr`, `profile`, `id`
FROM
    `list`
GROUP BY
    `class`,
    `discipline`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как посчитать итоговую сумму по столбцам(лекции, семинары, лабораторные). По каждому столбцу, отдельно. Создавать второй запрос, или все таки можно изменить этот?

Comment: уже сам вид запроса (большое кол-во функций в нем) показывает что вам нужен не второй запрос и не изменение этого, а генератор отчетов.

Comment: А какой генератор можно использовать?

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы делаете и на какой платформе, это очень такой, обширный вопрос

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `class`, `discipline`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_students`, 0)) AS `count_students`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лекция', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `lection`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Семинар', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `seminar`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `lab`,
    SUM(`type`='Лекция') AS `groups`,
    SUM(`type`='Лабораторная') AS `subgroups`,
    count('id') AS `numbe`,
    `course_semestr`, `profile`, `id`,
    (SUM(IF(`type`='Лекция', `count_hours`, 0))                       -- 
   + SUM(IF(`type`='Семинар', `count_hours`, 0))                      --
   + SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_hours`, 0))) as total_hours -- исправление здесь
FROM
    `list`
GROUP BY
    `class`,
    `discipline`;
```

либо так:

```
SELECT *
      , (`lection` + `seminar` + `lab`) as total_hours FROM
    (SELECT `class`, `discipline`,
        SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_students`, 0)) AS `count_students`,
        SUM(IF(`type`='Лекция', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `lection`,
        SUM(IF(`type`='Семинар', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `seminar`,
        SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `lab`,
        SUM(`type`='Лекция') AS `groups`,
        SUM(`type`='Лабораторная') AS `subgroups`,
        count('id') AS `numbe`,
        `course_semestr`, `profile`, `id`
    FROM 
        `list`
    GROUP BY 
        `class`,
        `discipline`);
```

А про генераторы отчетов все таки поищите информацию.

P.S. Сорри, неправильно понял вопрос, и соответственно дал неправильный ответ, данное решение дает сумму трех столбцов, а не итоговую сумму по каждому из них, правильный ответ у @Alex используйте WITH ROLLUP

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.  Но результат запроса выдает, что не существует столбца lab. Про генераторы нужно почитать. Это наверное будет правильное решение